How to have a waiting message during an async FluentValidation in Blazor?
I'm writing an application in Blazor and I'm using the FluentValidation package. I'm trying to have a spinner during the async validation process without any success.
Regards
Al
 RuleFor(r => r.OriginalOrder)
     .NotEmpty()
     .WithMessage(loc[nameof(Resources.Orders.ExistingOriginalOrderNumberRequired)])
     .MustAsync(async (originalOrder, cancellation) =>
     {
            ShowSpinner()

            try
            {
                var result = await wsRequester.GetReturnAsync(...)

                if (result.RequestResult == WSRequester.RequestResult.Success)
                {
                    return result.DTOReturn.Any();
                }

                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                HideSpinner()
            }
     }).WithMessage(loc[nameof(Resources.Orders.ExistingOriginalOrderNumberRequired)]);


I recommend you to call the spinner before the Validator. In orders: ShowSpinner => Await the validator => HideSpinner
